# c# Concurrency and order - Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Tags: .net, concurrency

I have a small problem: I got an object Log. This object fires an event when it's write function is called. The write function is not necessary called on the current applications dispatcher. So assume the following code:

```
protected void OnLoggingEnqueuedMessage(object sender, EnqueuedMessageEventArgs e)
{
    if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        AddLogEntry(e.LogEntry);
    else
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { AddLogEntry(e.LogEntry); }), null);
}
```

If Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() returns false the order of items added can be messed up. I understand that operations enqueued with BeginInvoke are not necessary executed in the same order as BeginInvoke is called but how can i add the items in correct order?

Comment: That's not it.  You are assuming that OnLoggingEnqueuedMessage gets called in some kind of order.  There is no such order between threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said:

> I understand that operations enqueued with BeginInvoke are not necessary executed in the same order as BeginInvoke

however the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx) states

> If multiple BeginInvoke calls are made at the same DispatcherPriority, they will be executed in the order the calls were made.

and as you are not specifying a DispatcherPriority your calls will have the same priority.

Comment: So i dont understand why the order of items is messed up

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that at runtime you are getting log entries that you know are out of order? If Yes, then i would try calling BeginInvoke every time, even if you're on the correct dispatcher.

Comment: as its possible your sync calls are 'beating' your async (`BeginInvoke`) calls to your `AddLogEntry` method

Comment: Ok I did some further investigation: The AddEntry seem to be called in correct order... (I output everything with Debug.WriteLine) but the data is displayed wrong in my DataGrid (WPF, Databound...). @wal I marked your answer because the issue seems to be somewhere else...

Comment: @Malone: thanks, the question&answer will still be of some use.